# Best practise of using view model in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have few doubt using viewmodel in composable function. I am adding my activity code, I am passing my intent bundle.

1. So I want to ask is this best practise to use viewmodel like this to create `viewmodel` global in the activity?

**InputActivity.kt**

```
class InputActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModel<InputViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupViewModel()
        setContent {
            Theme {
                AppBarScaffold(
                    displayHomeAsUpEnabled = true,
                    titleId = R.string.personal_health
                ) {
                    viewModel.OptionData?.let {
                        Input(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel.optionData = intent.getParcelableExtra("optiondata")
    }
}
```

I have so many composable function

**Input**

```
@Composable
fun Input(optionData: OptionData) {
    var value by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        InputItem()
        Spacer()
        OnSubmitPulse()
    }
}
```

**InputItem**

```
@Composable
fun InputItem() {
    Image()
    PulsePressure()
}
```

**PulsePressure**

```
@Composable
fun PulsePressure() {
    Column {
        InputWithUnitContainer()
        InputWithUnitContainer()
    }
}
```

**InputWithUnitContainer**

```
@Composable
fun InputWithUnitContainer() {
    Row() {
        Text()
        TextField(value = "")
        Text()
    }
}
```

Every function have logic which I want to store in viewmodel.

2. So should I create viewmodel in constructors parameters or pass viewmodel instance every time ?

**Scenario 1**

```
fun Input(optionData: OptionData,viewModel: InputViewModel = viewModel())
```

**and**

```
fun InputItem(viewModel: InputViewModel = viewModel())
```

**and**

```
fun PulsePressure(viewModel: InputViewModel = viewModel())
```

**Scenario 2**

```
fun Input(optionData: OptionData,viewModel: InputViewModel = viewModel()) {
        InputItem(viewModel)
}
```

**and**

```
fun InputItem(viewModel: InputViewModel) {
      PulsePressure(viewModel)
}
```

**and**

```
fun PulsePressure(viewModel: InputViewModel) {
    // more function call
}
```

So what would you guys suggest in jetpack compose. Please ask me if you don't understand me question. Many Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is not only one best practice but choosing approaches that suits your needs.

You should decide if your ViewModel needs to be in memory while your app is alive or scoped to navigation graph or a Composable.

Second thing to consider is if you will use same Composable in another screen or another app. If so, instead of passing ViewModel to Composable you might consider passing states as params and events to ViewModel via a callback.

Instead of this

```
fun Input(optionData: OptionData,viewModel: InputViewModel = viewModel()) {
        InputItem(viewModel)
}
```

I tend to go with this if i need to use, or think i will use `Input` in different sections or in another app in the future

```
fun Input(optionData: OptionData, someOtherData, onOptionDataChanged:()->Unit, onSomeOtherDataChanged: () -> Unit) {
        InputItem(viewModel)
}
```

[State in jetpack Compose from codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#11) is a good article to read about this subject.

```
@Composable
fun WellnessScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, 
    wellnessViewModel: WellnessViewModel = viewModel()
) {
   Column(modifier = modifier) {
       StatefulCounter()

       WellnessTasksList(
           list = wellnessViewModel.tasks,
           onCheckedTask = { task, checked ->
               wellnessViewModel.changeTaskChecked(task, checked)
           },
           onCloseTask = { task ->
               wellnessViewModel.remove(task)
           }
       )
   }
}

@Composable
fun WellnessTasksList(
   list: List<WellnessTask>,
   onCheckedTask: (WellnessTask, Boolean) -> Unit,
   onCloseTask: (WellnessTask) -> Unit,
   modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
   LazyColumn(
       modifier = modifier
   ) {
       items(
           items = list,
           key = { task -> task.id }
       ) { task ->
           WellnessTaskItem(
               taskName = task.label,
               checked = task.checked,
               onCheckedChange = { checked -> onCheckedTask(task, checked) },
               onClose = { onCloseTask(task) }
           )
       }
   }
}

@Composable
fun WellnessTaskItem(
   taskName: String,
   checked: Boolean,
   onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
   onClose: () -> Unit,
   modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
   Row(
       modifier = modifier, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
   ) {
       Text(
           modifier = Modifier
               .weight(1f)
               .padding(start = 16.dp),
           text = taskName
       )
       Checkbox(
           checked = checked,
           onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange
       )
       IconButton(onClick = onClose) {
           Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = "Close")
       }
   }
}
```

Last but not least if it's UI logic that is not dependent of any business logic or if you are building a standalone custom Composables as counterpart of custom Views you can consider capturing UI logic in a class that is wrapped in `remember` instead of ViewModel.
Examples for this approach are any rememberX functions we use with Lists, Scaffolds and other default Composables.

`remmeberScrollState` for instance

```
@Stable
class ScrollState(initial: Int) : ScrollableState {

    /**
     * current scroll position value in pixels
     */
    var value: Int by mutableStateOf(initial, structuralEqualityPolicy())
        private set

    /**
     * maximum bound for [value], or [Int.MAX_VALUE] if still unknown
     */
    var maxValue: Int
        get() = _maxValueState.value
        internal set(newMax) {
            _maxValueState.value = newMax
            if (value > newMax) {
                value = newMax
            }
        }

    /**
     * [InteractionSource] that will be used to dispatch drag events when this
     * list is being dragged. If you want to know whether the fling (or smooth scroll) is in
     * progress, use [isScrollInProgress].
     */
    val interactionSource: InteractionSource get() = internalInteractionSource

    internal val internalInteractionSource: MutableInteractionSource = MutableInteractionSource()

    private var _maxValueState = mutableStateOf(Int.MAX_VALUE, structuralEqualityPolicy())

    /**
     * We receive scroll events in floats but represent the scroll position in ints so we have to
     * manually accumulate the fractional part of the scroll to not completely ignore it.
     */
    private var accumulator: Float = 0f

    private val scrollableState = ScrollableState {
        val absolute = (value + it + accumulator)
        val newValue = absolute.coerceIn(0f, maxValue.toFloat())
        val changed = absolute != newValue
        val consumed = newValue - value
        val consumedInt = consumed.roundToInt()
        value += consumedInt
        accumulator = consumed - consumedInt

        // Avoid floating-point rounding error
        if (changed) consumed else it
    }

    override suspend fun scroll(
        scrollPriority: MutatePriority,
        block: suspend ScrollScope.() -> Unit
    ): Unit = scrollableState.scroll(scrollPriority, block)

    override fun dispatchRawDelta(delta: Float): Float =
        scrollableState.dispatchRawDelta(delta)

    override val isScrollInProgress: Boolean
        get() = scrollableState.isScrollInProgress

    /**
     * Scroll to position in pixels with animation.
     *
     * @param value target value in pixels to smooth scroll to, value will be coerced to
     * 0..maxPosition
     * @param animationSpec animation curve for smooth scroll animation
     */
    suspend fun animateScrollTo(
        value: Int,
        animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float> = SpringSpec()
    ) {
        this.animateScrollBy((value - this.value).toFloat(), animationSpec)
    }

    /**
     * Instantly jump to the given position in pixels.
     *
     * Cancels the currently running scroll, if any, and suspends until the cancellation is
     * complete.
     *
     * @see animateScrollTo for an animated version
     *
     * @param value number of pixels to scroll by
     * @return the amount of scroll consumed
     */
    suspend fun scrollTo(value: Int): Float = this.scrollBy((value - this.value).toFloat())

    companion object {
        /**
         * The default [Saver] implementation for [ScrollState].
         */
        val Saver: Saver<ScrollState, *> = Saver(
            save = { it.value },
            restore = { ScrollState(it) }
        )
    }
}
```

### Extra

Also depending on your needs or applicability favoring using states with `Modifier` over `Composable` might make it easy to use with other Composasbles.

For instance

```
class MyState(val color:Color)

@composable
fun rememberMyState(color:Color) = remember{MyState(color)}
```

Wrapping UI logic inside Modifier

```
fun Modifier.myModifier(myState:State)= this.then(
   Modifier.color(myState.color)
)
```

might have more reusability than Composable in some scenarios

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(myState: MyState) {
   Column(Modifier.background(color){...}
}
```

If you use a `Composable` in the example above we limit layout to `Column` while you can use first one with any `Composable` you wish. Implementation depends on what's your preferences are mostly.

Comment: Good points you mention in the post. Great to hear that.... Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

> 1.So I want to ask is this best practise to use viewmodel like this to create viewmodel global in the activity?

It is more common to declare it inside of the onCreate function, as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

```kotlin
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Use the 'by viewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
        // from the activity-ktx artifact
        val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
        exampleFunction(viewModel)
    }
}
```

and then pass the viewModel to the functions that require it, declaring the global viewModel seems a bit... anty-pattern, I've never seen it set-up like that but it should work

> 2. So should I create viewmodel in constructors parameters or pass viewmodel instance every time?

passing the viewModel instance (so scenario 2) would be enough, there doesn't seem to be a reason to keep multiple instances of the same viewModel at once (especially if all of them contain some `init` functions)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way is using [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal).

As per your example,

```
//Composition Local Kept outside activity
    val VMCompositionLocal = staticCompositionLocalOf<InputViewModel> {
        error("No Escrow Viewmodel provided")
    }
    
    class InputActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
        private val viewModel by viewModel<InputViewModel>()
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setupViewModel()
            setContent {
                Theme {
                    AppBarScaffold(
                        displayHomeAsUpEnabled = true,
                        titleId = R.string.personal_health
                    ) {
            // This will provide view model instance to Input Component.
                        CompositionLocalProvider(VMCompositionLocal provides viewModel){
                            Input()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private fun setupViewModel() {
            viewModel.optionData = intent.getParcelableExtra("optiondata")
        }
    }
```

You can access view model from Input composable function like this.

```
@Composable
fun Input(){
//This binds the view model instance that is provided to this Input() from setContent
var viewModel = VMCompositionLocal.current
var optionData = viewModel.optionData
}
```

Comment: Text at your link says: "An example of a bad practice is creating a CompositionLocal that holds the ViewModel of a particular screen so that all composables in that screen can get a reference to the ViewModel to perform some logic. This is a bad practice because not all composables below a particular UI tree need to know about a ViewModel."